# OCaml Mutex module cannot be found

Tags: ocaml, mutex

I tried to use Mutex module, such as Mutex.create(), but compiler says Unbound module Mutex. Does it require some special namespace? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *toplevel*:

```
ocaml -I +threads

# #load "unix.cma";;
# #load "threads.cma";;
# Mutex.create ();;
- : Mutex.t = <abstr>
```

For *ocamlc*:

```
ocamlc -thread unix.cma threads.cma src.ml
```

For *ocamlopt*:

```
ocamlopt -thread unix.cmxa threads.cmxa src.ml
```

For *findlib*:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -thread -package threads -linkpkg src.ml
```